# dev cpp win32 the program can't start because sqlite3.dll is missing

Tags: winapi, sqlite, static-libraries, dev-c++

1. I am using dev c++ IDE which used ming gcc(i am not sure of it)
2. I wanted to use sqlite3 in my win32 c application
3. I downloaded sqlite3.dll and sqlite3.dev and used dlltool to create a .a file like libsqlite3.a and pasted in the lib folder of dev cpp and added this path in the project options -> parameters
4. i copied the header file sqlite3.h into the include folder(which i got from another website - http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/SQLite/SQLite-74/derived_source/sqlite3.h)
5. i executed the program and got the message 'the program can't start because sqlite3.dll is missing in your computer'
6. so i copied the sqlite3.dll into my working directory and then it worked

BUT

How to make the sqlite.* static while compiling?

I mean i thought by including the libsqlite3.a, the final exe will not be dependent of any external dll's.

So i want to know how to compile in a way that i will not be needing a dll and by doing so it makes my windows program standalone.

do i have a create a .lib file instead of .a file?

**EDIT after answers and comments**:
Besides, the devpak is working fine... yet i wanted to know how to include files to project or to create .a files so i am trying this way because if some components do not provide devpak then this will be the way we need to compile.. isn't it?

**EDIT to show what i have done after the answer by CL and the two comments**

**This is how i have added the sqlite.c to project list**

[image]

**Here is the compile log**

> Compiler: Default compiler
>
> Building Makefile:
>   "C:\Users\jayapalc\Documents\test-sqlite\Makefile.win"
>
> Executing  make...
>
> make.exe -f "C:\Users\jayapalc\Documents\test-sqlite\Makefile.win" all
>
> g++.exe -c sqlite3.c -o sqlite3.o -I"lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include" 
>   -I"include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"include"
>
> sqlite3.c: In function `void strftimeFunc(sqlite3_context*, int,
>   sqlite3_value**)':
>
> sqlite3.c:14727: error: invalid conversion from `void*' to`char*'

**The files i got in sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3071502.zip are**

shell.c, sqlite3.h, sqlite3.c, sqlite3ext.h and i saw in other discussions that shell.c is not needed...

**Besides**, people were talking about gcc and g++... .

Comment: Please update your IDE to the following version, which fixes an immense list of bugs, ships with GCC 4.7.1 (x64) or 4.7.2, and is fully portable: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from updating Dev-C++ itself, try this to compile sqlite.c as a C file:

- Go to Project >> Project Options >> Files.
- Find the C file we're talking about. Untick "Compile file as C++".

This should inform Dev-C++ that it should invoke gcc.exe, and not g++.exe.

If you don't want to compile sqlite yourself by adding it to your project, you can try passing the -static flag to GCC/G++ to force it to link libsqlite.a statically.

Answer (score 1):

Just include the [sqlite3.c](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) file in your project.

You need only this filed, and it must be compiled as C, not C++.

Apparently, Dev-C++ does not allow mixing C and C++ source files in one project.
Instead, you could try to compile `sqlite3.c` as C and then include the generated .o file into the C++ project (on the Linker page).

Comment: how do i include it? to the project properties like adding libraries or as a header... just tried as a header and got many invalid conversion errors... usually a component use to give a .a file and a header file... but ... here i am not getting how to go ahead.

Comment: As a source file, just like your other C/C++ files.

Comment: yes i did... yet i got invalid conversions... i have updated my question with edit captions. besides, i read the same issue in other discussion but not sure of what he did... here is the link ... http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/24340/

Comment: yeah. that worked. thank you. besides, what i did was i  created a new project and selected as a c project and it worked.(previously i had been selecting as cpp project). so by selecting c project the gcc is used and by selecting c++ project g++ is used... is my assumption right?

Comment: and what should i do if i want to make that work with c++ project? i mean by selecting as c++ project and want to use sqlite3.c will it work? or it is that sqlite3.c is specially only for c projects and not for c++... ?